# compute matrix gradient symbolically, of a quadratic scalar objective function.

Tags: matrices, optimization, vector-analysis, closed-form

My dearest Exchangers,

Let me summarize two questions that I have.
I need to compute a matrix gradient of the scalar function $$
J =\|A\hat x_k - x_{k+1}\|_2^2, 
$$ with respect to the 2-by-2 matrix $A$. 
First, what is the correct way to compute this gradient?
I came up with the following nonsense:
$$\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial J}{\partial a_1} &  \frac{\partial J}{\partial a_2} \\
\frac{\partial J}{\partial a_3} & \frac{\partial J}{\partial a_4}\end{bmatrix} &=
\begin{bmatrix}
(\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & a_2
\end{bmatrix}-x_{k+1,1})\hat x_{k,1} & (\begin{bmatrix}a_1 & a_2\end{bmatrix}-x_{k+1,2})\hat x_{k,2} \\
(\begin{bmatrix}a_3 & a_4\end{bmatrix}-x_{k+1,1})\hat x_{k,1} & (\begin{bmatrix}a_3 & a_4\end{bmatrix}-x_{k+1,2})\hat x_{k,2}
\end{bmatrix} \\
& = \begin{bmatrix} A \hat x_k - \begin{bmatrix}x_{k+1,1} \\
x_{k+1,1}\end{bmatrix} & A \hat x_k - \begin{bmatrix}x_{k+1,2} \\x_{k+1,2}\end{bmatrix}\end{bmatrix} \hat x_k
\end{align} 
$$

But (if this is correct), I don't know how to further simplify this expression, in such a way that I only use the symbols that are used in $J$. With what I got now, it seems that I need to stack some elements manually into vectors. Obviously, when dimensions become large, it is unhandy/non-elegant to do this with a for loop in optimization. It would be nice, if I would have to only use the said variables, present in $J$.

My other question is, if I have found a gradient, for which I would think it is correct, then how can I check whether this is correct? The only way I know of currently, is to make that objective and use computed gradient to update said parameters, and see if $J$ indeed decreases. But probably this is not a sufficient check. But mainly I would be happy already, If I would know how to correctly compute that gradient! (Maybe there are some standard rules to use when matrices/vectors are present in an objective function, that I do not know of.)

---

By the way, I hope that it is apparent what symbols are elements of what variables, otherwise please ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For typing convenience, let me use the symbols 
$$\eqalign{
 x &= {\hat x}_k \cr
 y &= x_{k+1} \cr
 w &= Ax-y \cr
}$$
I will also use a colon to represent the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{A:B &= {\rm tr}(A^TB)}$$
Now I can write the cost function in terms of these symbols and find its differential and gradient
$$\eqalign{
 J &= \|w\|^2 = w:w \cr
dJ &= 2w:dw = 2w:dA\,x = 2wx^T:dA \cr
\frac{\partial J}{\partial A} &= 2wx^T = 2(Ax-y)x^T\cr
}$$
To test the correctness of these expressions, first calculate $J$ for some value of $A$. Then add a small random perturbation to the matrix (let's call it $dA$) and calculate the change in the cost function
$$\eqalign{
 J_0 &= \|Ax-y\|^2 \cr
 J_1 &= \|(A+dA)x-y\|^2 \cr
\Delta J &= J_1-J_0 \cr
}$$
Compare this to the change predicted by the differential
$$\eqalign{
 dJ &= 2(Ax-y)x^T:dA \cr &= 2(Ax-y)^T\,dA\,x \cr
}$$
You should find that $\,\,dJ \approx \Delta J$